# Converting Plaintext from a text box to SHA1 Then Sha1 to base 64 C#

Tags: c#, mysql, base64, sha1

Ok i want to generate a sha1 hash from plaintext textbox then convert the hash to base64 to store in a mysql database how do i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        string s = "abc";
        byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s);
        SHA1 algorithm = SHA1.Create();
        byte[] hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(data);
        string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
```

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Excuse me for be a beginner jeez

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I apologize for that i didnt mean to come off like that how would i have the output go in to a textbox so i can run my update query to my database?

Comment: @gothicdude1044: that seems a little different that what you've asked above, but: `textBox.Text = base64`.